# How to get object from array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to get status and message from these array.
I don't know how to map.

```
[<null>, {
    message = "Not matched";
    status = 400;
}]
```

This is my code

```
class QRScanValidAPIMapper: NSObject {
    var message: String!
    var status: Int!

    init(_ rawData: Any) {
        print(rawData)
        let data = rawData as? Dictionary<String,Any>
        self.message = data?["message"] == nil ? rawData as! String : data?["message"] as! String
        self.status = data?["status"] == nil ? 0 : data?["status"] as! Int
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the first part of your question what `print(rawData)` prints?  so you have a null first element in the array ?

Comment: let mappedResponse = QRScanValidAPIMapper(data)  i added the data.  @u.gen

Comment: Are you sure `{
    message = "Not matched";
    status = 400;
}` is identical dictionary in that Array ?

Comment: If `rawData` is an array as what you seem to be showing, your cast to `Dictionary<String,Any>` will always fail.

Comment: Yes sure QR data gave me that. @AmirKhan

Comment: Can u please tell me how to cast @shim

Comment: Ok let me fix this. I hope that Array will be same as you describe for all failure scenario.

Comment: @RedHeart check my answer below.

Comment: It's hard to say from your question, but presumably you should cast it as `[Dictionary<String,Any>?]` or just `[[String: Any]?]` for brevity's sake. But you should determine why you have that null value in your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `failure` dictionary from `Array` and get the value from it. like this -

```
let array = [nil, ["message" : "Not matched", "status" : 400]]

for response in array {

        if let failureResponse = response {

            print(failureResponse["message"]!)
            print(failureResponse["status"]!)
        }
}
```

Let me know whether you are still having any issue.

Comment: I got this error in line 6  **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Any'**

Comment: @RedHeart Can you add `line 6` ?

Comment: `for response in array {}` this line -

Comment: @RedHeart what is `array` data type?

Comment: if let failureResponse = array as?  [String: Any] {} i need to add this code ` as?  [String: Any] {}`  Thanks bro